# How to create an average, rank, total measures over a field (by dynamic period) in SSAS

Tags: average, ssas, mdx, calculated-columns, rank

I'm new with SSAS technology and I have an existing cube that measures hits by page on web site.
In few words the cube is structured as followed:

- a dimension 'Expression' that contains reference to pages with DOI property as identifier.
- a dimension 'Date' to filter hits by period with hierarchical properties (year, month, day)
- a measure 'successful hits' that contains hits by DOI by date (one hit is recorded by timestamp, no aggregation by DOI)

So it's quiet simple to get results like this:
[image: page hits by year]

But I want also to get average, total and rank of hits by page and period like this (manually edited into Excel):
[image: average, total and rank of hits by page and period]

I tried to add a calculated measure to get the average by adding first a property to aggregate the count of hits : [Measures].[Hits count]

Then calculated [Average Hits] : [Measures].[Successful Hits]/[Measures].[Hits Count]

But all I get is 1 (because the [Measures].[Successful Hits] is equal to [Measures].[Hits Count]...)
How can I have :

- average of count by period
- total by period
- rank by item

Hope it's clear...
Thank you for your help!